# Static gcloud token?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm new to using the Google Cloud suite and I'm trying to build a simple python script that calls the Vision API for document text extraction on a set of files. To do so, I have replicated the instructions found here:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#vision_text_detection-drest

Currently my python script looks something like this:

```
key = <my_api_key>
url = 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=' + key
access_token = <my_access_token>
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
           'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
```

where access_token is determined by

```
$ gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

(Normally, running using curl in bash I would replace access_token with $(gcloud auth ...).) Next,

```
import base64
import json
import requests
with open(file, 'rb') as f : 
    encoding = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode('ascii')
    request = {'requests': [{'features': [{'type': 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION'}],
                             'image': {'content': encoding},
                             'imageContext': {'languageHints': ['en']}}]}
    with open('request.json', 'w') as r :
        r.write(json.dumps(request))
    with open('request.json') as d : 
        response = requests.post(url = url, data = d, headers = headers)
```

i.e. I convert 'file' to base64, create the requests.json file then POST it.

I'm not very familiar with authentication so here is my question: at the moment the only authentication I have is, from what I can tell, an API key and a service account. I used the service account json file in to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and that allows me to call

```
$ gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

The only issue I'm facing is that the token seems to expire. So I have to (a) go back to bash, set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, call the above command again, then copy and paste the token into my code. Is there an out-of-the-box type solution that allows me to have a static token or a static way to run my script?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using requests with the rest api instead of the [wrapper library](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision) provided by google? That libary takes care of all the authentication and adds some abstractions that make working with the vision api a lot easier.

Comment: No particular reason - I'll use it if necessary but I generally just translate my successful tests (e.g. using the api) into python to avoid any hassle in depending on libraries and have (usually) more flexibility. I guess I wasn't anticipating any issues migrating my tests into python. Thanks for the suggestion though - I'll use the library if I can't find a solution here.

Comment: They also have a module specifically for authentication [google-auth](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python). You could try using that one if you want to keep third party requirements to a minimum.

Comment: @swenzel's recommendation is good. Please don't reimplement auth particularly when Google provides this for you and makes it very easy. See: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python

Comment: If you really want to implement authentication yourself, check [this doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest) on how to request access token from within your app to later refresh it.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments - I decided to follow the advice and used the python library for authentication. @EmilGi - it seems you are right as well, upon reading the documentation it seems the token must be refreshed if the session expires. I'll post a solution using the wrapper library.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who commented - it seems the easiest way to authenticate is using a service account and the associated .json file, rather than adding GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to path.

```
from google.cloud import vision
service_account_json = <my_service_account_json>
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient.from_service_account_json(service_account_json)
```

Parameters can still be passed into the request by sending the request as a dict (equivalent to the usual json).

```
def annotate (filename) :
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f :
        encoding = f.read()
    request = {'image': {'content': encoding},
               'features': [{'type': 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION'}],
               'image_context': {'language_hints': ['en']}}
    response = client.annotate_image(request=request)
    return response
```